# Forward Geocoding with MapKit

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

Does the MapKit library support the Forward Geocoding (process of turning the textual address into longitude/latitude), if not, what will be the solution, because i need that feature in my iPhone application. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Apple docs for CLGecoder:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder

Pre iOS 5 there is no support directly in Apple's frameworks. You'd probably want to use Google's geocoding API to get support before iOS 5. i.e. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/